# Sharing SecureString SSM Parameter Value Between Different Accounts

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

Code Pipeline stack is running in AccountA and there is a SecureString SSM paramemter created in this account.
Code Pipeline creates another stack that is deployed in AccountB and it needs the decrypted value of SecureString SSM paramemter declared in Account A.

I have been trying to get the decrypted value using below options without any luck:

```
//const value= SecretValue.ssmSecure('/CodeBuild/key', '1').unsafeUnwrap();
//const value = SecretValue.ssmSecure('/CodeBuild/key', '1').resolve.toString();
  const value =
            ssm.StringParameter.fromSecureStringParameterAttributes(
            this,
            'imported-param-3',
            {parameterName: '/CodeBuild/key', version: 1},
        ).stringValue;
```

The plan is pass the decrypted value to AccountB stack either as a property or as a parameter.
All I am getting is below value instead of the decrypted value.

```
{{resolve:ssm-secure:/CodeBuild/key:1}}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where are you getting that? This is a token that CloudFormation will try to resolve during deployment. You are probably trying to view it before deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a very similar issue using EKS and SSM and for me it was a permissions issue. Ensure that Account B has permissions to access secrets manager. Additionally, ensure that there is a policy for secrets manager in Account A that lets Account B read it.

To verify that this is indeed the issue, you can look at Cloudtrail in Account B to see into the API command. That is how you can tell where your access is being denied.